# Loop through a grid in Sheet 1, return cell reference with formula in a column on Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large grid in Sheet 1, there are 365 columns, each one being one day of the year, starting with January 1st.

The rows correspond to manufacturing sites, there are many of them as well.

There is nothing in Sheet 2, but what I would like is a large list in the first column of Sheet 2 that has all of the cell references for the grid.

More specifically, I would like VBA to insert `IF(ISBLANK("A1","","A1))` so that if the cell is empty, nothing is returned and if there is a value, that value is returned.

I am still learning VBA and I am not sure how to run a loop on the first column, then move to the second column, run the loop....

Comment: why use VBA? Do you need to ensure no blank rows? If not, I would just do this with Excel formulas and apply a filter to sort the blank rows to the bottom. If this is acceptable, let me know and I can give an example as a solution.

Comment: Sheet 2 isn't actually blank, it has the row and column headings concatenated (Manufacturing Site #1, January 1) and linked to Sheet 1.   So there are thousands of combinations that each need a cell reference next to them.  I wish I could just drag the formula down from the top, but Sheet 2's formatting is fixed and if I change the order I won't be able to get it back to the way it was, I think

Comment: `I wish I could just drag the formula down from the top, but Sheet 2's formatting is fixed...` Type the formula in Cell A1 and then copy cell A1 and do a paste special Formulas on the relevant range :) No VBA is required for this :)

Comment: thanks for all the input, Siddharth - that works for all the manufacturing sites on January 1st, but once the column needs to be switched to January 2nd, that doesn't work.  I'd have to manually change the column reference for each day and then do it again.  Unless I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use vba, you can do this to copy a formula to a whole range:

```
Sub doIt()

  Dim lastRow As Long

  lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

  With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1:NA" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!RC),"""",Sheet1!RC)"
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Sub copyFilledCells()

Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim position As Integer


position = 1

Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_1").Range("A:AZ")

For Each c In r
    If (c.Value <> "") Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_2").Range("A" & position).Value = c.Value
       ' Try this if you want to insert the cell address as Formula
       'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_2").Range("A" & position).Formula = "=" & c.Parent.Name & "!" & c.Address(External:=False)

        position = position + 1
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: getting a run time error 9 - subscript out of range for "set r = "

Comment: it was the underscore "Sheet_1" --> "Sheet1"

Comment: that worked, one more addition, how can I get it to return the cell location/reference instead of the value (ie, instead of 100, return "=Sheet1 !A1" that way if the value changes in Sheet1, Sheet2 will auto update

Comment: `c.Parent.Name & "!" & cell.Address(External:=False)`
will return the cell adress

Comment: Try this: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_2").Range("A" & position).Formula = "=" & c.Parent.Name & "!" & cell.Address(External:=False)`